# fadeToggle() same image fades differently

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video, fadeout

Just started with code. I know very little. Tried putting everything I have in JSFIDDLE... it just doesn't seem to work.

There is a background image. On top of it a video. And on top of the video there is a title that spans across the whole page.

When I try fadeToggle to eliminate all but the video, the part of the title that's exactly on the video disappears quickly while the rest of the same title (not overlapping the video) fades out nicely along with the background image as I have set it to fadeToggle(1500).

Why is the same image (the title, not the background. the background fades fine) chopped up when faded?

Thanks guys!

Comment: Link us to the JSFIDDLE please

Comment: Anything rendered "on top of the video" is likely to have animation problems as fading needs to be calculated based on the layers below it. You will likely get different results on different browsers as some may include the current video frames in the fade and others will not.

Comment: Post your code in your question. Then, optionally, add a link to your jsFiddle. Sites like jsFiddle should supplement the code in your question, not act as a substitute for it.

Comment: Thank you for your help guys! I decided to go with the title above the video. It looks better. But I also now understand that it involves browser capabilities and calculating fading. This is great thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It could be because when the fadeToggle starts, the render puts the video over the image, so it disappears. You can try setting `style="z-index: 100"` to the image and see if this way you can force it to stay in top... Also, if you could try removing the video before the image is fully faded you would know for sure if it is behind the video or not.

Anyway, this seems to be the kind of problem that some browsers can handle and some browsers can't.

Comment: I do have the z-index to 100 on that title. Thanks. I decided to go with the title above the video. I'm sorry for not providing the jsfiddle. Thank you so much though.